# Using Foreign Keys: Getting a column from another table using the id column

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL so I've yet to venture very far into multi-table usage.

Here are my tables:

Client table->

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_table (
player_id SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
playername varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (player_id),
UNIQUE KEY playername (playername)
) 
COLLATE latin1_general_ci, ENGINE = INNODB
```

Data table ->

```
CREATE TABLE Data_table ( 
data_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
timestamp datetime NOT NULL, 
player_id SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
action TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
data varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (data_id), 
KEY timestamp (timestamp), 
KEY player (player_id)
) COLLATE latin1_general_ci, ENGINE = INNODB;
```

What i'm trying to do is link the `player_id` from `player_table` to my `SELECT` statement. So when i select all the data from `Data_table`, I want to get a `playername` NOT a `player_id` in combination with the rest of the data `Data_table` holds. Is there anyway to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Left Join OR Inner Join** as per your requirement

```
    SELECT 
      D.*,
      P.playername 
    FROM Data_table D
    LEFT JOIN player_table P ON P.player_id=D.player_id
```